# How to validate a single attribute for a submitting ActiveRecord instead of all its attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to validate a single attribute for a submitting ActiveRecord instead of all its attributes.

For example, in my model I have:

```
validates :firstname, :presence => true, ...
validates :lastname,  :presence => true, ...
```

I would like to *run validation on the `:firstname` and on the `:lastname` separately*. **Is it possible? If so, how can I make that?**

---

P.S.: I know that for validation purposes there are methods like "validates_presence_of", "validates_confirmation_of", ..., but I would like to use only the above code.

Comment: What do you mean `separately` ? Will there be 2 calls to save for example, or just one? What is the use case/scenario of what you're trying to do overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a virtual attribute on your model, and then do conditional validation depending on that attribute.

You can find a screencast about this at http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

Answer (score 1):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base  
  def save(*attrs)
    Model.validates :firstname, :presence => true if attrs.empty? || attrs.include?( :firstname )
    Model.validates :lastname,  :presence => true if attrs.empty? || attrs.include?( :lastname )
    ...
    super
  end
end

m = Model.new
m.save
#=> false
m.save(nil) # same as save(false), you can use both of them
#=> true
m = Model.new :firstname => "Putty"
m.save
#=> false
m.save(:firstname, :lastname)
#=> false
m.save(:firstname)
#=> true
```

Comment: Nice. But won't this override the `save(options={}) ` method from `ActiveRecord::Validations` so that `save(false)` will no longer work? Not sure about this, but maybe you've already taken that into account?

Comment: @Zabba, good point, but actually `save(false)` will ignore all validations because `attrs` won't be empty and there aren't any column_names with name `false`. But yes - it is quite hacky and we can simply refactor this method :)

Answer (score -3):

You can just delete the second line of your code above so it reads:

```
validates :firstname, :presence => true
```

No validation will then be performed on the :lastname.

Regards

Robin

Comment: I would like to validate ':firstname' and (then) validate ':lastname' separately, so I need the second part.